# Two dynamic JTable overlapping with JPanel

Tags: java, swing

I have a JPanel containing 2 JTables. Only one table should be visible at a time, when I click a button.

My problem is when I click button one, it shows me table 1, and when I click button two, it shows me table 2, which overlap table 1.

I want table 1 to be removed before showing table 2. I tried `repaint()` and `revalidate()` but nothing works.

Comment: use CardLayout.

Comment: can you please show us your code?

Comment: use table1.setVisible(false); to hide it in the panel when you click.

Comment: [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take a tour [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need only one table on a JPanel at a time , Clear the JPanel on Button click and add the table required on basis of button pressed.

You may use the following functions for the same :

```
jpanel.remove(table_ref)
or
jpanel.removeAll()
```

After removing the first table add the second table .

```
jpanel.add(table_ref);
```

Just remember the following after adding the table .

```
jpanel.revalidate();
jpPanel.repaint();
```

revalidate and repaint will help to refresh the jpanel.

Answer (score 2):

show this example, i use `CardLayout`

```
JPanel cardPanel = new JPanel(new CardLayout());
cardPanel.add("table1", new JTable());
cardPanel.add("table2", new JTable());

// when you want to show table1 and hidden table2
((CardLayout)cardPanel.getLayout()).show(cardPanel, "table1");
```